# All numbers from the start to end numbers will be added to a listbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

you have two textboxes for start and end number; upon hitting a button, all numbers from the start to end numbers will be added to a listbox

Comment: What is the question? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
int startNum, endNum;
if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out startNum) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out endNum))
{
    for(int i = startNum; i <= endNum; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save those textboxes value to a string and use for, or foreach loop to iterate through.
You can check with this, if the char is number or not. If its number, add to the listbox.

```
int n;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse("123", out n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
int start = 5, end = 10;
var items = Enumerable.Range(start, end-start).ToList();

// add the items to listbox
```

You can also check for validation like end > start.

Answer (score 0):

after you get the value of the textBoxes,

```
int start;
int.TryParse(textBox1.text, out start);
int end;
int.TryParse(textBox1.text, out end);
```

then you need to write a loop,
you can use this:

```
List<int> result = Enumerable.Range(start, end-start).ToList();
```

or

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
      result.Add(i);
}
```